# Solidity: Error Member "value" not found or not visible after argument dependent look up in the function address

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to make the funds withdrawn from 3 accounts automatically after a certain event. I am unable to fix this error from the Remix IDE. Please can someone let me  know what am I doing wrong... The function is payable

> Member "value" not found or not visible after argument dependent look up in the function address. Did you forget the "payable" modifier

```
function SignTermsAndConditions() OnlySender_Receiver_Transporter{
    if(msg.sender == sender){
        require(state == contractState.waitingForVerificationbySender);
        SignedBy("Terms and Conditiond verified : ", msg.sender);
        state = contractState.waitingForVerificationbyTransporter;
    }else if(msg.sender == transporter)
    {
        require(state == contractState.waitingForVerificationbyTransporter);
        SignedBy("Terms and Conditiond verified : ", msg.sender);
        state = contractState.waitingForVerificationbyReceiver;
    }
    else if(msg.sender == receiver){
        require(state == contractState.waitingForVerificationbyReceiver);
        SignedBy("Terms and Conditiond verified : ", msg.sender);
        state = contractState.DoneVerificationofTerms;
        POD_PhysicalItems.withdrawAgreedUponCollateral.value(2*itemPrice)(sender);
        POD_PhysicalItems.withdrawAgreedUponCollateral.value(2*itemPrice)(transporter);
        POD_PhysicalItems.withdrawAgreedUponCollateral.value(2*itemPrice)(receiver);
    }
}

function withdrawAgreedUponCollateral(address entityAddress) payable internal  {
    require(state == contractState.DoneVerificationofTerms);
    collateralWithdrawnSuccessfully("Double deposit is withdrawn successfully from: ", entityAddress);

}
```

Comment: How `POD_PhysicalItems` is declared? Is it a contract?

Comment: yes it is the name of the contract

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a call to contract class, you need a contract instance.

```
POD_PhysicalItems physicalItems = POD_PhysicalItems(physicalItemmsAddress);
physicalItems.withdrawAgreedUponCollateral.value(2*itemPrice)(sender);
```

Where `physicalItemmsAddress` is the address of the deployed `POD_PhysicalItems` contract.